# Pandas - Converting date column from dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe (df) that has a date column (column name : sale_date) that stores data in the below format

```
dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss
```

I am trying to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Tried with the below but however it still does not convert it to the required format.

```
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'])
```

Could anyone assist in converting the format of this date column. Thanks

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` should convert to a datetime, and you should then be able to format how you want. Why are you needing it in that specified format? You can use `dt.strftime` to convert to any format, but it converts the column to a string, not a datetime.

Comment: @KenSyme, Thanks for the reply. I am trying to get a date column value returned..

Comment: Does your `to_datetime` line not work for that? Are you getting an error? What output do you get and what are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you know you will have a consistent format in your column, you can pass this to `to_datetime`:

```
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

If your formats aren't necessarily consistent but do have day before month in each case, it may be enough to use `dayfirst=True` though this is difficult to say without seeing the data:

```
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 25):

You can do so:

```
df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Input:

```
           sale_date
0  04/12/10 21:12:35
1  04/12/10 21:12:30
```

Output:

```
             sale_date
0  2010-12-04 21:12:35
1  2010-12-04 21:12:30
```