# Date and time conversion in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A .csv file has a date column. When read into a pandas DataFrame and displayed, the date and time are displayed as:

```
2021-06-30 19:39:25
```

The correct date is `30-06-2021 19:39:25`

How can this be changed?

Comment: somehow duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724883/pandas-converting-date-column-from-dd-mm-yy-hhmmss-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss

Comment: The date is not *incorrect*, it is just displayed in a different format.

Comment: @RufusVS Agree that the format was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using pandas.to_datetime method to convert date format will be more reliable

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] , format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: This worked with change as below (as per the time string formatting in the original dataframe):
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: @user1955215 but `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` is already within `Date` column as you say, what was the expected then?

Comment: I feel that although the display looked like a time, the column format was an object (string). On using the above, it started behaving like a datetime...(Not sure as to the cause of the problem earlier.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `strftime`:

```
>>> date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
'30-06-2021 19:39:25'
>>>
```

Comment: The date got converted correctly for 30th June. For 1st June, the original displayed date 06-01-2021 08:05:21  remains unchanged. The expected date was "01-06-2021 08:05:21"

Answer (score 1):

try below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2021-06-30 19:39:25', '2021-07-22 19:39:25', '2021-08-18 19:39:25']})
# convert `Date` column to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

### Solution:

```
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] , format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

 if the above doesn't work then use belwo..

# Now convert to desired format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(df)
0    30-06-2021 19:39:25
1    22-07-2021 19:39:25
2    18-08-2021 19:39:25
Name: Date, dtype: object
```